# UDP Client without real ip address

Tags: java, php, sockets, udp

I am trying to make an application which consist of a Java UDP client and a PHP UDP server. I am thinking about binding the server with the client over internet, because the client may not have real/public ip address. Though the server is a web application itself which will open a listener on the public address over some port. The task of the client is to communicate (send/receive) data over UDP.

Communicating parts:

- Client: Windows/Linux OS connected to Internet (Java application)
- Server: Windows IIS Server,  with a real ip and domain (PHP web application)

Comment: Have you considered trying it?

Comment: "real ip"? you mean the client will be behind a NAT gateway? That won't matter to the server. If the client can send udp to a "public ip", then the server will see that udp packet arriving from the nat gateway's external IP. Replying (server->client) may be problematic, because the nat gateway won't know what the reply packet is...

Comment: Communicating parties:
Client: Windows/Linux OS connected to Internet (Java application)
Server: Windows IIS Server,  with a real ip and domain (PHP web application)

Answer (score 1):

This will depend on the firewalling/NAT-ing policy at a given client site, but the usual setup is to allow UDP out to the server and then allow corresponding reply packets back in, based on source and destination addresses and port numbers.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a problem if you were to try and create a server behind your router.

Your router will replace the client's local ip address with the public ip address of your router at the moment that you send something to the server. The router will internally keep a translation table. This translation table is consulted when the server sends a reply to retrieve the original IP adress where the request originated and then the reply is simply forwarded to that IP address. As such it seems as if you are using the ip@ that is allocated for you usually using DHCP by your router. But this local ip@ is never seen on the internet only on your local lan.

Because the translation table is built by you trying to send to a server, you cannot easily setup a server behind your router. Simply because your router will not have an entry in its translation table to route the request coming from the internet to your server. This is called NAT/PAT. Because the translation table keeps track of ip adressen and ports.

All IP addresses are real. But people talk about a public IP@ and a local IP@. The public IP@ is the one that is used on the internet where the local ip@ is the one that you use on your local LAN.